# How I can specialize template when a method is available?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, function-templates

I wonder how I can have a specialized template for when my type has a specific method. Let's take the following code as an example:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(T&& arg, Args&&... args) 
{
    std::cout << "called 1\n";
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::log)>, int> = 0>
void foo(T&& v)
{
    v.log();
}

struct Y
{
    void log() const 
    {
        std::cout << "called 2\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo(1); // <-- print "called 1";
    Y y;
    foo(y); // <-- print "called 2";
}
```

I should say that this code does not work (2nd `foo` will use main template and prints `called 1`) and I know I cannot partially specialize a function call, but it shows what I need.

Any idea how I can achieve something like this? Should I use structures to partially specialize and then use helper functions?

Comment: BTW, you don't specialize, but provide overloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the good track, but, with forwarding reference,

`decltype(&T::log)` becomes `decltype(&(Y&)::log)` which is invalid.

Using [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) solves your issue:

```
template<typename T, 
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&std::decay_t<T>::log)>,
        int> = 0>
void foo(T&& v)
{
    v.log();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d9e9491663f48f1)

Comment: ouch.....I could not see the problem, because when I remove main template, this one will be called even without decay. I wonder why is that.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to be that much verbose; You can enable the other `foo`, by as follows:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T&& v) -> decltype(v.log(), void())  
{
    v.log();
}
```

**([See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rGdfP6E3K))**

It is called the [trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function). You provide the `decltype` to evaluate the expressions (1. `v.log()`, 2. `void()`) with [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) separation. If the first expression(i.e. `v.log()`) fails, the overload is not the suitable one to call. Hence, it goes for the other `foo`. Otherwise, it accepts this overload with `void` return, which is evalued from the `void()` expression!

Comment: Thanks. what is 2nd one?it is not specialization, is  it? Why it is selected over main template?

Comment: But why it is tested first at all? Because in case of my code, it is not checked at all. My 2nd template is valid, but it will not be checked till I remove main template.

Comment: @Afshin For the function call `foo(1);` which one is suitable? The one with triadic args? or  the single one? Single arg right? Therefore, it checks the single one first and the other.

Comment: Aha, I got what you mean :)